# Objectify entities - reusing issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In my app I would like to create entities that can be reused by many different data sources (e.g. I want to cache some of them in Redis) - in JPA I can use annotations which are not affecting on semantic of entities (i.e. they can be ignored by different services and a entity can acts as POJO). In Objectify, to create a relationship, I need use classes like Ref or Key in my entities' definition, that changes their semantic.

My question is - is there any way to create POJO entities which can be used with Objectify and which can be used with relations features? I would prefer to not use any kind of DTOs to achieve that if it is not required (i.e. use a different entity for Objectify and a different for rest of data sources - it can increase complexity and create duplications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit the nail square on the head here : Since you need to change the semantic of your definition for Objectify, it won't work unfortunately.

You will need to stay with JPA, or JDO, and work from there.

Comment: I think the same - I created a proxy for Objectify temporaly, but in the future I will move on JPA.